# Type in assembly is not marked as serializable Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, save

I have a MonoBehaviour class PlayerDistanceScript which contains player variables and some of game logics.
[image: PlayerDistanceScript]
[image: PlayerDistanceScript]
I am using it to pass the score to SaveSystem class:
[image: SaveSystem]
and inside it I'm calling for PlayerData constructor to pass the player data.
[image: PlayerData]
When I am trying to save the data to a file "formatter.Serialize(stream, data);" is showing me the Error: SerializationException: Type 'PlayerDistanceScript' in Assembly 'Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

What is the best way to avoid this error? Thanks for help

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with this problem. My answer is not very precise, but I hope it will help.
As I remember, MonoBehaviour is created by Unity team using C++, it has bunch of hidden properties. It cannot be serialized, just like GameObject cannot, for example. So, as your script is not big, I can recommend this:
Create new non-MonoBehaviour class in your PlayerDistanceScript file. Remove your properties from this script and add them to created class. Then, in PlayerDistanceScript create an object of your created class and serialize it, use its properties where it is necessary. Do not forget to mark that class and its properties serializable.
If you have to serialize Unity type object, like Text, you cannot go straightforward. If you really need it, you can save its key values like position, size etc. and serialize them.
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

All models have to set `[System.Serializable]` on top of the class.

For example:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerModel 
{
    public string name;
    public List<Items> items = new List<Items>();
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Items
{
   public string name;
   public float damage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error when trying to save/load more complex objects, like GameObjects or scripts extending MonoBehaviour.

If you need to save a GameObject, you might have to save the components of the GameObject instead. Then when loading create an instance and populate the components with the saved data.